# Concatenação em função verifica

Tags: php, javascript, html5

```
$linkBloquear = '
  <a href=
      "?produtos&bloquear&idProdutos=' . $produtos->getIdProdutos() . '"
      onclick="return verifica(' . $mensagemBloquear . ');" 
   >
' . $imagemBloquear . '
</a>';
```

Postei dessa forma para que facilite a visualização.

Estou co,m problemas na função **verifica**

Da forma que está

```
(' . $mensagemBloquear . ')
```

Vai sair algo como:

```
return verfica (Tem mesmo que verificar?)
```

E vai dar erro;

Tentei:

```
(\"' . $mensagemBloquear . '\")
```

e sai algo como:

```
return verfica (\Tem mesmo que verificar?\)
```

Como corrijo isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava na colocação das aspas aqui:

```
onclick="return verifica(\'' . $mensagemBloquear . '\');"
```

Ao invés de colocar aspas simples escapadas estava colocando aspas duplas:

```
onclick="return verifica(\"' . $mensagemBloquear . '\");"
```

Answer (score 0):

Em JavaScript tens 3 marcadores de String, usa string template "`".

```
onclick="return verifica(`' . $mensagemBloquear . '`);"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use algo do tipo, use essa forma de concatenar.

```
$linkBloquear = "<a href='?produtos&bloquear&idProdutos=123' onclick='return verifica(\"{$mensagemBloquear}\");'>Teste</a>";
```